# Hide dock notification badges with Do Not Disturb enabled in macOS

Tags: macos, mac, notifications, dock, do-not-disturb

I remember in previous versions of macOS whenever DND mode was enabled the app icon badges in the dock would be disabled. This makes sense as I do not want to be disturbed by my "unread" count judging me.

Since I updated to Big Sur this feature is gone. A google search comes out empty, with only an app by an independent developer as the solution, but the app's website is gone.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I'm struggling with this exact same problem. 